# Oracle - Counts by time intervals

Tags: oracle, time, intervals

I have a table with some entries, and a DATE column indicating the date/time the record was inserted.   What I need is to create a query where the data will be displayed in a tabular format with counts at the 15 minute intervals for the entire day.   So, the output would look like:

```
LABEL   DAY       DATE       00:00   00:15   00:30   00:45.........23:30   23:45
ORDERS  MONDAY    4/19/2021    1       1       0       1             0       1
ORDERS  TUESDAY   4/20/2021    1       0       0       0             1       0
```

This is what they are asking for......and probably have to put that into a CSV at some later date.  But for now, is there any simple way to make a query like this, or are we talking writing a procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT label,
       TO_CHAR(TRUNC("DATE"), 'DAY') AS day,
       TRUNC("DATE") AS "DATE",
       COUNT( CASE TRUNC(("DATE" - TRUNC("DATE"))*96) WHEN 0 THEN 1 END ) AS "00:00",
       COUNT( CASE TRUNC(("DATE" - TRUNC("DATE"))*96) WHEN 1 THEN 1 END ) AS "00:15",
       COUNT( CASE TRUNC(("DATE" - TRUNC("DATE"))*96) WHEN 2 THEN 1 END ) AS "00:30",
       COUNT( CASE TRUNC(("DATE" - TRUNC("DATE"))*96) WHEN 3 THEN 1 END ) AS "00:45",
       COUNT( CASE TRUNC(("DATE" - TRUNC("DATE"))*96) WHEN 4 THEN 1 END ) AS "01:00"
       -- ...
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY TRUNC( "DATE" ), label
ORDER BY TRUNC( "DATE" ), label
```

Or `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(dt,'FMDAY') AS day,
       t.*
FROM   (
  SELECT label,
         TRUNC("DATE") AS dt,
         TRUNC( ("DATE" - TRUNC("DATE")) * 96 ) AS time
  FROM   table_name
)
PIVOT(
  COUNT(*) FOR time IN (
     0 AS "00:00",
     1 AS "00:15",
     2 AS "00:30",
     3 AS "00:45",
     4 AS "01:00",
     5 AS "01:15",
     -- ...
    92 AS "23:00",
    93 AS "23:15",
    94 AS "23:30",
    95 AS "23:45"
  )
) t;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1db016aa84b58d857db559a3ce77c9a5)*

Comment: Thanks.  This will work.  I figured Oracle might have a more elegant way to do this, but apparently not........appreciate it/

Comment: @LandonStatis Simplified it a bit and added a method using `PIVOT`.

Comment: Yes, the PIVOT definitely works better........much appreciated.

Comment: Now, can I take this, and convert it into a comma delimited string?   Then it can be pulled into Excel, etc.........

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to describe as detailed as I can.

First of all you can truncate your minutes to 15 minutes intervals:

```sql
--test data:
with t(label,dt) as (
select 'ORDERS',date'2021-04-21'+numtodsinterval(level*2,'minute') 
from dual 
connect by level<=30
)
--main query:
select 
    dt, label, weekday, hh24, quarter, quarter*15 rounded_minutes
from
    (
    select 
        dt
       ,label
       ,to_char(dt,'day') weekday
       ,to_char(dt,'hh24') hh24
       ,trunc(to_number(to_char(dt,'mi'))*4/60) quarter
    from t
    );
```

Results:

```
DT                  LABEL  WEEKDAY    HH24    QUARTER ROUNDED_MINUTES
------------------- ------ ---------- ---- ---------- ---------------
2021-04-21 00:02:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            0               0
2021-04-21 00:04:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            0               0
2021-04-21 00:06:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            0               0
2021-04-21 00:08:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            0               0
2021-04-21 00:10:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            0               0
2021-04-21 00:12:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            0               0
2021-04-21 00:14:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            0               0
2021-04-21 00:16:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            1              15
2021-04-21 00:18:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            1              15
2021-04-21 00:20:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            1              15
2021-04-21 00:22:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            1              15
2021-04-21 00:24:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            1              15
2021-04-21 00:26:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            1              15
2021-04-21 00:28:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            1              15
2021-04-21 00:30:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            2              30
2021-04-21 00:32:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            2              30
2021-04-21 00:34:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            2              30
2021-04-21 00:36:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            2              30
2021-04-21 00:38:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            2              30
2021-04-21 00:40:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            2              30
2021-04-21 00:42:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            2              30
2021-04-21 00:44:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            2              30
2021-04-21 00:46:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            3              45
2021-04-21 00:48:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            3              45
2021-04-21 00:50:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            3              45
2021-04-21 00:52:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            3              45
2021-04-21 00:54:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            3              45
2021-04-21 00:56:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            3              45
2021-04-21 00:58:00 ORDERS wednesday  00            3              45
2021-04-21 01:00:00 ORDERS wednesday  01            0               0
```

As you can see we calculate a quarter of hour using simple `trunc(to_number(to_char(dt,'mi'))*4/60)`. So we just need to multiply it to 4 to get rounded minutes.

Then you can just concatenate them and use `pivot` clause to aggregate:

```sql
with t(label,dt) as (
select 'ORDERS',date'2021-04-21'+numtodsinterval(level*2,'minute') 
from dual 
connect by level<=3000
)
select *
from (
    select 
        label, weekday, hh24||':'||to_char(quarter*15,'fm00') hhmi
    from
        (
        select 
            dt
           ,label
           ,to_char(dt,'day') weekday
           ,to_char(dt,'hh24') hh24
           ,trunc(to_number(to_char(dt,'mi'))*4/60) quarter
        from t
        )
    )
pivot(
 count(*) for hhmi in (
  '00:00','00:15','00:30','00:45','01:00','01:15','01:30','01:45'
 ,'02:00','02:15','02:30','02:45','03:00','03:15','03:30','03:45'
 ,'04:00','04:15','04:30','04:45','05:00','05:15','05:30','05:45'
 ,'06:00','06:15','06:30','06:45','07:00','07:15','07:30','07:45'
 ,'08:00','08:15','08:30','08:45','09:00','09:15','09:30','09:45'
 ,'10:00','10:15','10:30','10:45','11:00','11:15','11:30','11:45'
 ,'12:00','12:15','12:30','12:45','13:00','13:15','13:30','13:45'
 ,'14:00','14:15','14:30','14:45','15:00','15:15','15:30','15:45'
 ,'16:00','16:15','16:30','16:45','17:00','17:15','17:30','17:45'
 ,'18:00','18:15','18:30','18:45','19:00','19:15','19:30','19:45'
 ,'20:00','20:15','20:30','20:45','21:00','21:15','21:30','21:45'
 ,'22:00','22:15','22:30','22:45','23:00','23:15','23:30','23:45'
 )
);
```

Results (shortened for readbility):

```
LABEL  WEEKDAY       '00:00'    '00:15'    '00:30'    '00:45'    '01:00'    '01:15' ...    '23:15'    '23:30'    '23:45'
------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ... ---------- ---------- ----------
ORDERS friday              8          7          8          7          8          7 ...          7          8          7
ORDERS saturday            8          7          8          7          8          7 ...          7          8          7
ORDERS sunday              8          7          8          7          8          7 ...          0          0          0
ORDERS thursday            8          7          8          7          8          7 ...          7          8          7
ORDERS wednesday           7          7          8          7          8          7 ...          7          8          7
```

Comment: This is good, but when I replace DUAL with my table name, and the hard coded date with the date column of the table, the query just runs, and never returns.  There are only 300 records in the table so far, so I'm not sure why the query would not complete........

Comment: @LandonStatis have you removed `connect by` clause? That's there just to generate more rows.